# apply or for loop for multiple variables

Tags: r, for-loop

I have two list of dates I would like to apply to my code ( first date in xx and first date in yy, then second date in xx and second date in yy, etc). (I have a short list of dates for the example).  trade1 is empty so I am approaching this wrong.

```
xx= c('2018-06-28','2018-07-27')
yy= c('2018-07-12','2018-08-13')

for (xx in seq_along(yy)) 
{
entry_trades = filter(aa2, Date == xx )%>%
          rename(entry_price = Price, entry_date = Date)
exit_trades = filter(aa2, Date == yy)%>%
         rename(exit_price = Price, exit_date = Date)
trade1 = merge(entry_trades, exit_trades,by='ticker')
trade1 = mutate(trade1, Chg = exit_price - entry_price,
            Chg_pct = round((Chg / entry_price)*100 ,1))%>%
arrange(desc(Chg_pct))
}
```

Comment: Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: You have a vector of dates `xx`, but then you call your loop variable `xx` - now `xx` is just a number like 1 or 2 and you aren't accessing your original date vector at all within the loop. Use a different name for the loop variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i in seq_along(yy)) 
{
entry_trades = filter(aa2, Date == xx[i] )%>%
          rename(entry_price = Price, entry_date = Date)
exit_trades = filter(aa2, Date == yy[i])%>%
         rename(exit_price = Price, exit_date = Date)
trade1 = merge(entry_trades, exit_trades,by='ticker')
trade1 = mutate(trade1, Chg = exit_price - entry_price,
            Chg_pct = round((Chg / entry_price)*100 ,1))%>%
arrange(desc(Chg_pct))
}
```

There's probably a better way of doing whatever you're trying to do, but I'm not sure what that is, and you didn't give us `aa2` so it's kind of hard to figure it out